# Sort descending struct in golang

Tags: xml, sorting, struct, go

Please see [this playground](http://play.golang.org/p/O6k9Km1l-C). What I want is quiet simple: I want to sort all "records" descending. I cannot figure out how. Reason is that my struct contains one or more records and I'm not sure how to handle that. (f.e. [this](http://play.golang.org/p/OHCN9S4G-E) works fine)

Comment: It looks like you've just blindly cut-n-pasted code from elsewhere without the slightest clue of what's going on. That approach just isn't going to work well for you no matter what you're doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [your example](http://play.golang.org/p/O6k9Km1l-C), you are trying to sort the root element `<records>` instead of the sub-elements `<record>`.

[This example](http://play.golang.org/p/8oTCNG0-Di) works better, with:

- `type ById []Record`
- `sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(ById(records.Records)))`

Your `Len()`, `Swap()` and `Less()` methods remain unchanged, but use as a receiver a `Record` instance instead of `Records`.

Output:

```
{{ records} 
  [{{ record} 64321 http://golang.com} 
   {{ record} 3456 http://www.lommers.org/sampleurl} 
   {{ record} 4 http://www.this-is-my-url.com}]}
```

---

As I mention in "[How to avoid re-implementing sort.Interface for similar golang structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40667316/6309)", this changes with Go 1.8 and [commit ad26bb5](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ad26bb5e3098cbfd7c0ad9a1dc9d38c92e50f06e):

You only define a `Less()` anonymous lambda

```
a := ById(records.Records)
sort.Slice(a, func(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i] > a[j]
})
```

Comment: If you really want to do the sorting by on `ReadingListRecords` (or just on `[]Records` as VonC suggests, but definitely *not* on `[]ReadingListRecords` as you have it) you just need to change your `sort.Interface` methods to, you know, actually work with `ReadingListRecords`. E.g. len(a.Records); a.Record[i], a.Record[j], etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `sort.Interface` implementation that sorts in ascending order, you can use the [`sort.Reverse`](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Reverse) function to produce a version that will sort in reverse.

So if `data` implements `sort.Interface` and you have a call like:

```
sort.Sort(data)
```

Then you can switch to descending order by changing it to:

```
sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(data))
```

Internally, the sorter returned by `sort.Reverse` just proxies the `sort.Interface` method calls straight through with the exception of `Less` where it switches the two arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not able to sort in the first place :). Can you please have a look at my playground (http://play.golang.org/p/O6k9Km1l-C)? I don't know what to pass to the sort function.